# combine arrays with the same name from same object into a single object with all items

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js

I'm new with Vue and I am not really sure it's possible to generate what I want, But I have this structure **:**

```
{
  "items":[
    {
      "total":1287,
      "currency":"USD",
      "name":"string",
      "itemID":"",
      "product":{
        "code":"3425",
        "name":"product one"
      },
      "fabrics":[
        {
          "code":"123",
          "name":"cotton",
          "status":"Verified",
          "vendors":[
            {
              "name":"sameVendor",
              "value":"vendor 1",
              "type":"",
              "description":"string"
            },
            {
              "name":"sameVendor",
              "value":"vendor 2",
              "type":"",
              "description":"string"
            },
            {
              "name":"sameVendor",
              "value":"vendor 3",
              "type":"",
              "description":"string"
            },
            {
              "name":"differentVendor",
              "value":"extra vendor",
              "type":"number",
              "description":"string"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "code":"345",
          "name":"polyester",
          "status":"confirmed",
          "vendors":[
            {
              "name":"vendorNumber",
              "value":123456,
              "type":"number",
              "description":"string"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "total":1277874,
      "currency":"USD",
      "name":"string",
      "itemID":"",
      "product":{
        "code":"2452",
        "name":"product 2"
      },
      "fabrics":[
        {
          "code":"654",
          "name":"wool",
          "status":"original",
          "vendors":[
            {
              "name":"vendorDate",
              "value":"date",
              "type":"date",
              "description":"string"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
<template>
    <div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "renderBasedOnFabrics",
  data() {
    return {
      vendors: []
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

What i want to achieve is for each object in items, for each object in fabrics to display a div with code and name if the vendors name are the same value, and if not if it's type number to display an input number instead.
i think i know how to loop in html using v-for, but i'm not really sure how can i get the vendors with the same name for fabrics vendors in each object in item array and create a rule in html based on that.

do i need to manipulate the items array first, and somehow save a new structure in data(), and after use the new array in html with v-for?

i'm really new with vue and don't know exactly what is the best approach or if it's possible to get what i want.

the outcome should be something like this **:**

```
<div>
 cotton 123 
 <div> sameVendor : vendor 1, sameVendor: vendor 2, sameVendor: vendor 3</div>
 <input type="number" id="differentVendor" name="extra vendor"
      >
</div>
<div>
  wool 654
  <div> vendorDate: date </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you only want to show items which meet a specific condition, the right approach is to filter the array by that condition before you pass it to DOM (so the `v-for` should run on the filtered array). If you want to display all items and, based on the condition to display one thing or another, than you need a method taking an item as argument and returning if the condition is `true` for the passed item. And use that method in a `<template v-if="myCondition(item)">...one thing...</template><template v-else>...another...</template>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, You want to make the input elements dynamically based on the `type`. If `type` is an empty string then it will be a normal label else it will create an `input` field based on the type. If Yes, Here is the live demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    allData: {
      "items":[
        {
          "total":1287,
          "currency":"USD",
          "name":"string",
          "itemID":"",
          "product":{
            "code":"3425",
            "name":"product one"
          },
          "fabrics":[
            {
              "code":"123",
              "name":"cotton",
              "status":"Verified",
              "vendors":[
                {
                  "name":"sameVendor",
                  "value":"vendor 1",
                  "type":"",
                  "description":"string"
                },
                {
                  "name":"sameVendor",
                  "value":"vendor 2",
                  "type":"",
                  "description":"string"
                },
                {
                  "name":"sameVendor",
                  "value":"vendor 3",
                  "type":"",
                  "description":"string"
                },
                {
                  "name":"differentVendor",
                  "value":"extra vendor",
                  "type":"number",
                  "description":"string"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "code":"345",
              "name":"polyester",
              "status":"confirmed",
              "vendors":[
                {
                  "name":"vendorNumber",
                  "value":123456,
                  "type":"number",
                  "description":"string"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "total":1277874,
          "currency":"USD",
          "name":"string",
          "itemID":"",
          "product":{
            "code":"2452",
            "name":"product 2"
          },
          "fabrics":[
            {
              "code":"654",
              "name":"wool",
              "status":"original",
              "vendors":[
                {
                  "name":"vendorDate",
                  "value":"date",
                  "type":"date",
                  "description":"string"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, i) in allData.items" :key="i">
    <div v-for="(fabricItem, j) in item.fabrics" :key="j">
      <h3>{{ fabricItem.name }} {{ fabricItem.code }}</h3>
      <div v-for="(vendorItem, k) in fabricItem.vendors" :key="k">
        <span v-if="!vendorItem.type">{{ vendorItem.name }} : {{ vendorItem.value }}</span>
        <input v-if="vendorItem.type" :type="vendorItem.type" :id="vendorItem.name" v-model="vendorItem.value"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers (and no, prefixing it with *"Try this:"* does not qualify as a non-code-only answer). Explain ***what*** you used and perhaps ***why*** (e.g: why you think that's the best method and superior to other methods). Links to documentation are always helpful, as they tend to help future visitors more than the implementation code itself. Ideally, you should consider your answers recipes for solving that type of problem, rather than solutions for one specific use-case.

Comment: @tao Thanks for pointing this out, I will keep this in my mind going forward. I updated the answer with the description.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal i appreciate ur answer but what i want to achieve is to display a div for each object and inside if the vendors within the vendors array have the same name to display the value for each of them inside a div, and if in that array i have also different name to display an input type number along with that div.

Comment: @slepyhead this is how it is showing. For all the `sameVendor`, type is an `empty` string. So i added a check for `vendorItem.type`, you can change that to `vendorItem.name === 'sameVendor'`.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal sorry, u are right. that's perfect. thank you